# Prove have a set with exactly 12 subset

Tags: combinatorics

How to do this question?

Is there a set with exactly 12 subsets? Explain

Comment: Do you know how to count the number of subsets of a _finite_ set?

Comment: What do you know about the number of subsets of a set? Show us a few small examples. For instance, how many subsets does $\{1,2\}$ have?

Answer (score 4):

Pauline, the number of subsets of a finite set $X$ is given by $2^{|X|}$, where $|X|$ is the number of elements contained in $X$. 
Since there is no positive integer $k$ satisfying $2^k = 12$, the answer to your question is no.